# Pull five unique numbers from a range and display in Text boxes using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table of numbers like below in a excel sheet.
[Excel Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fly8z.jpg)

```
No1 No2 No3 No4 No5
1   190 134 190 101
10  142 117 10  151
155 12  12  12  128
154 154 154 154 154
```

I have a UserForm with 5 TextBoxes to display 5 unique numbers from the table.

When I click on the command button, It should pull 5 UNIQUE numbers from the above table and display it in the TextBoxes respectively.

Also, If I click on the command button again(i.e. Multiple Clicks to get more result), It should populate a different **UNIQUE** numbers from the table.

I used simple if else concept to achieve this but it is not working correctly.

Please assist me to achieve the result. Thank you!

I use the below code:

```
Private Sub btnGenerate_Click()

Dim PresentRow As Byte, PresentColumn As Byte

PresentRow = ActiveCell.Row
PresentColumn = ActiveCell.Column

If PresentRow = 5 And PresentColumn = 1 Then
    Sheet1.Range("F2").Activate
ElseIf PresentRow = 5 And PresentColumn = 5 Then
    Sheet1.Range("A2").Activate
End If

Select Case ActiveCell.Column

 Case 1
     TextBox1.Text = ActiveCell.Value

     If ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value <> TextBox1.Text Then
         TextBox2.Text = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
     Else
         TextBox2.Text = ActiveCell.Offset(1, 1).Value
     End If

     If ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value <> TextBox2.Text Then
         TextBox3.Text = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value
     Else
         TextBox3.Text = ActiveCell.Offset(1, 2).Value
     End If

     If ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Value <> TextBox3.Text Then
         TextBox4.Text = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Value
     Else
         TextBox4.Text = ActiveCell.Offset(1, 4).Value
     End If

     If ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4).Value <> TextBox4.Text Then
         TextBox5.Text = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4).Value
     Else
         TextBox5.Text = ActiveCell.Offset(1, 5).Value
     End If

 Case 5

     TextBox1.Text = ActiveCell.Value

     If ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Value <> TextBox1.Text Then
         TextBox2.Text = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Value
     Else
         TextBox2.Text = ActiveCell.Offset(1, -1).Value
     End If

     If ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2).Value <> TextBox2.Text Then
         TextBox3.Text = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2).Value
     Else
         TextBox3.Text = ActiveCell.Offset(1, -2).Value
     End If

     If ActiveCell.Offset(0, -3).Value <> TextBox3.Text Then
         TextBox4.Text = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -3).Value
     Else
         TextBox4.Text = ActiveCell.Offset(1, -4).Value
     End If

     If ActiveCell.Offset(0, -4).Value <> TextBox4.Text Then
         TextBox5.Text = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -4).Value
     Else
         TextBox5.Text = ActiveCell.Offset(1, -5).Value
     End If

End Select
Sheet1.Activate
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Does it pick the numbers at random from the table?  Can you please post your current code for populating the textboxes?

Comment: Help us to help you **post your current code.**

Comment: Hmmm, if you are unwilling to [edit] your question to include your code (the code you refer to in your narrative) I can only assume you've abandoned this question so posting a solution would be kind of pointless.

Comment: Hello All, Apologies for the delay. I have updated the code. Thanks!

Comment: @ tigeravatar: Yes, it can be random numbers but from the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> <sup>The following requires that **Microsoft Scripting Runtime** be added to the project via Tools, References.</sup>

In the worksheet code sheet:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim txt As Long, vals As Variant, ky As Variant
    Dim uniq As New Scripting.Dictionary

    vals = Range("A2:E5").Value2
    uniq.RemoveAll

    Do While uniq.Count < 5
        uniq.Item(vals(Application.RandBetween(LBound(vals, 1), UBound(vals, 1)), _
                       Application.RandBetween(LBound(vals, 2), UBound(vals, 2)))) = vbNullString
    Loop

    TextBox1 = uniq.Keys(0)
    TextBox2 = uniq.Keys(1)
    TextBox3 = uniq.Keys(2)
    TextBox4 = uniq.Keys(3)
    TextBox5 = uniq.Keys(4)

End Sub
```

[image]